# HTML table with more than 10 rows sorting is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I'm having a problem with my table that wont be sorted (desc) if I have more than 10 rows in the table. It works perfectly if I have 10 or less rows but not more. Here's my code:

```
function sortAndFadingRows(rowId) {
    var $row = $(rowId);
    var oldRowIndex = $row.index();
    sortTable();
    var newRowIndex = $row.index();
    if (newRowIndex < oldRowIndex) {
        $row.children().effect('highlight', { color: '#fff' }, 1000);
    }                             }



var sortTable = function () {
    var table = $("#tableId");

    var sorts = table.find(".item").detach().toArray();
    sorts.sort(function (a, b) {
        var valA = parseInt($(a).find(".myValue").text());
        var valB = parseInt($(b).find(".myValue").text());
        return valA < valB; 
    });

   table.append(sorts);          };
```

I invoke `sortAndFadingRows(rowId)` every time I receive data, when I receive it I directly put it in a `td` in a specific column to sort the table according to this column. Then I send the row id to check if its index has changed or not. If the row jumps up (its index decreased) then I highlight it otherwise not. As I said, it works perfect if we have 10 or less rows but not more than 10. Anyone knows what I' doing wrong?

Comment: i think there should be problem with your data

Comment: sort functions must return **THREE** values: -1, 0, 1 for lessthan/equal/greater than. since you're returning a boolean, you only ever provide 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort comparator function is supposed to return a number, not a boolean. The `return` statement should be

```
    return valA - valB;
```

The comparator return value is interpreted as:

- a negative number means that the first item should be sorted before the second
- a positive number means that the second item should go before the first
- zero means that they can go in either order

The specification for the `.sort()` routine in JavaScript explicitly allows the algorithm to be *unstable*. That means that when your comparator returns `0`, the items *might* be re-ordered instead of being left in their original order.

If you need stability, you can add a comparison on some secondary key; that is, some other part of the row that isn't important if the primary keys are different.  To do that, you'd have to extract the secondary key if the first comparison results in a zero:

```
  // ...
  var result = valA - valB;
  if (result !== 0)
    return result;
  // Fetch secondary keys
  valA = parseInt($(a).find(".secondary").text());
  valB = parseInt($(b).find(".secondary").text());
  return valA - valB;
```

If there is no secondary key that would work as a meaningful way to preserve order, you could always pre-process the list before sorting to *add* a key, one that's based on the as-is ordering.

Comment: @raghavendra why do you say that? Do you know something about [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that I don't?

Comment: @Pointy I tried it with a reverse() to get it sorted desecending, it worked but not as good as my code, it had some issues.

Comment: @SamoZabo to sort in the reverse order, just `return valB - valA;` instead

Comment: @Pointy You're right but still the same issue. Ex: if i have position 1, 2 and 3 have the value 10 in each of them and the 4th has 9, the problem is when the 4th become 10 it will jump to the first position and push the other rows to the down positions. I want it to keep its position untill it become 11 then it's okay to pass the others

Comment: @SamoZabo well the JavaScript `.sort()` routines are not guaranteed to be *stable* - that means that when the comparison returns `0`, it *might* change the order of the elements. If you can sort on a secondary key, that can help. I'll extend the answer.

Comment: @Pointy Now I return false if valB - valA === 0 otherwise return valB - valA. and it's actually working fin yet and I don't know how long it will last. You gave me the hint :)! Thanks alot for helping!!

Comment: @SamoZabo That's probably wrong.  Returning `false` is exactly like returning `0`.

Comment: @Pointy well that's weird because it works just like it should. I'll try with the secondary key selution.